# How to: software firewall exception for Netbeans?

Tags: java, windows-firewall, netbeans

I was installing a plugin for Netbeans (Gradle Support); which in itself went fine. I had already installed it on another computer and am working with it successfully. However, on this particular install, when it was concluded a generic popup saying that Java was looking for permissions to access the internet came up. I denied the request - not realising this had to do with the Gradle install.

A consequence of this denial is that gradle is simply refusing to work correctly in Netbeans. Unfortunately, because Gradle isn't a programme (as such) I do not know how to grant retrospective permission. Granting Windows Firewall permissions to Netbeans has no effect. Reinstalling Netbeans, and the plugin, has no effect either.

Does anyone know how I might grant retrospective firewall permission to this Netbeans plugin?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is.

Comment: @Ramhound How to grant retrospective firewall permission to the Netbeans plugin

Comment: You should update your question.  Additional information on this "generic popup" would be helpful.  Was it a Windows Firewall prompt or something else?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows Firewall prompt. It mentioned Java - but to be honest I didn't pay it a huge amount of attention at the time (thinking it unimportant)

Comment: Call me old fashion.  A question in the written English language requires a question mark, so when somebody posts a question here at `Superuser`, I expect to see a least once complete sentence with a question mark.

Comment: @Ramhound using question/exclamation marks or words like "Hi", "Hello", "How", "Why", "Best", "Thanks", "Cheers", "Please", "Recommended", "Help" all seem to be frowned upon on stack exchange. I think one or two of those are banned from question titles in fact.

Comment: I would agree those words shouldn't be allowed in a question's title.  So why did you do it?  You modified your question to include an actual statement that is a question.  Your question's title still reads as your going to self-answer the question though.  I am half-expecting you to post an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound because I disagree with the policy and hope to stretch the rules enough to get an actual answer to the question without incurring moderator wrath

Comment: Those are not moderator rules they are community guidelines. Still waiting on information about the "generic popup" I suspect I have an answer but can't post an answer until I am sure.

Comment: @Ramhound If you have a possible answer I'd be happy to hear it! I'm afraid if you are waiting for more information from me about the generic popup you would be out of luck. If I could get the popup to display again (such that I could get a screenshot or take down anything about it) the problem would by definition be fixed (because in that case I could just accede to the demands of the plugin and the issue would be solved). I suppose I could setup a virtual windows OS and go through all the steps from scratch before hopefully taking a snapshot of a similar popup on the virtual OS but...v. long